# Graph of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

How to define the graph of a square matrix $\mathbf{G}$ with real entries?

I know that given a graph $\Gamma(V, E)$, one can define its adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$. But given a matrix $\mathbf{G}$ how to define its graph?

P.S. I was reading in this book [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Matrix_Analysis.html?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&redir_esc=y). There is a theorem that asserts that $\mathbf{A}$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Gamma(\mathbf{A})$ is strongly connected (where $\Gamma(\mathbf{A})$is the graph of $\mathbf{A}$). I do not know what is the definiton of the graph of a square matrix.

Comment: In no expert in graph theory, but doesn't it depends on what your problem is ? For example you can consider that a square matrix $G$ with elements $G_{i,j}$ represents the graph ie : $G_{i,j}\neq 0$ iif $i$ and $j$ are connected, with a weight $G_{i,j}$ for this edge.

Comment: I was reading in this book [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Matrix_Analysis.html?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&redir_esc=y). There is a theorem that asserts that $\mathbf{A}$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Gamma(\mathbf{A})$ is strongly connected (where $\Gamma(\mathbf{A})$is the graph of $\mathbf{A}$). I do not know what is the definiton of the graph of a square matrix.

Comment: There are two binary matrices that are often associated with a given simple graph, the [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) and the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).  I would expect the book you are reading to define the notion of "the graph of a square matrix" to give a variation on the adjacency matrix, since these are always square.  Perhaps you can add a page reference?

Comment: Did you perhaps overlook **Definition 6.2.11** in that book (page 399), which associates a directed graph $G$ with $n\times n$ square matrix $A$ having $n$ nodes with a directed edge from the $i$th node to the $j$th node whenever $a_{ij} \neq 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, if the matrix is $n\times n$ we define a directed graph with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, where there is an arc from $i$ to $j$ if $A_{i,j}\ne0$. This directed graph may have loops, but they do not affect whether the directed graph is strongly connected. It is not weighted.