# Irreducible Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a *strongly connected weighted digraph* with corresponding (weighted) adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{\geq0}$ and *out-degree* matrix $\mathbf{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{>0}$. Moreover, let $\mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the associated Laplacian matrix, i.e., $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{A}$.

My questions are the following.

a) I know that the strong connectivity of $\mathcal{G}$ implies that $\mathbf{A}$ is an irreducible matrix. However, what can we say about $\mathbf{L}$? Is $\mathbf{L}$ irreducible as well?

b) Let $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{\geq0}$ be any *diagonal* matrix with non-negative diagonal entries and let $\mathbf{M}= \mathbf{L} + \mathbf{B}$. Is $\mathbf{M}$ irreducible?

The goal is to prove that $\mathbf{M}$ is an *irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix* (which would then imply that $\mathbf{M}$ is nonsingular).

Any formal proof or reference that sheds some light onto my questions would be greatly appreciated. The main reference that I have been using so far is *Matrix Analysis*, Horn and Johnson, 2nd Ed.

Comment: $L$ has less zero elements than $A$, so it's irreducible as well. Unless you also have self-loops in your graph

Comment: Okay. I think I misunderstood the concept of "Graph of a matrix" (c.f., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748846). I thought that such an abstraction was limited to non-negative matrices only. However, it is not. Using the fact that a matrix is irreducible if and only if its associated graph is strongly connected, it immediately follows that both $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{M}$ are irreducible because $\mathcal{G}$ is strongly connected. Am I correct?

Comment: modifying the elements on the diagonal only affects the self-loops of the graph, that in turn doesn't influence the connectivity of the graph